# Angular ui router multiple named views for all states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know if there is any way to write multiple named view for all states, the best example is when i want the nav bar and footer to appear in all routes.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home',{
    views: {
      'home': {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: controller
      },
      'nav': {
        templateUrl: 'nav.html',
        controller:controller
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'footer.html',
        controller: controller
      },
    }
  })
```

I dont want to use ng-include, because the nav and the footer is showing before the home state is resolved in this case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can, its actually written in the `ui-router`'s guide on how to manage [**Multiple Named Views**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

First, you need to define a specific set of named views in an abstract state, including the view where you would put all your content views such as your `home.html` and put it in a nameless view (empty string).

As you may have noticed, the demo below shows a root state named `app`, which is also an abstract state (this means you can't navigate in this state). It has three views, each represents a name that corresponds to the `ui-view`s defined in the `index.html`.

Within the nameless view, contains the `content.html` that has a nameless `ui-view` that will represent all the child states of the `app` state. By doing this, you can share the `nav.html` and `footer.html` to all your states if you add these states under the `app` state. An example to this would be the `app.home` and `app.items` state. To learn more about this, read the link I've added above.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Uqakif2hs5NWH21mYFS?p=preview)**

***Javascript***

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
   nav: {
     templateUrl: 'nav.html',
     controller: 'NavController as Nav'
   },

   '': {
     templateUrl: 'content.html',
     controller: 'ContentController as Content'
   },

   footer: {
     templateUrl: 'footer.html',
     controller: 'FooterController as Footer'
   }

  }
})

.state('app.items', {
  url: '/items',
  templateUrl: 'items.html',
  controller: 'ItemsController as Items'
})

.state('app.home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController as Home'
});
```

***HTML***

*index.html*

```
<ui-view name="nav"></ui-view>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<ui-view name="footer"></ui-view>
```

*content.html*

```
<hr>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<hr>
```

Comment: Thank you, was looking for the exact explination. Someone just told me to use ng-include but I knew there was a better way staying within ui-router.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of your routes you can probably make use of the [abstract state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states) to do this:

[Angular UI Router - Views in an Inherited State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473096/angular-ui-router-views-in-an-inherited-state?rq=1) might also help point you in the right direction.